# Hiding the Keyboard at any Touch in Scroll View-Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scroll, keyboard

How can I hide the keyboard At any touch on the screen, on a view that has a scroll View.

I added this code into viewDidLoad function: 
self.NewAccountScrollView.keyboardDismissMode.UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag

And I added the UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode protocol! 
I got errors?

[image]

What should I add more to make this works? 
Is this the correct way to do that? or there are a better function to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this, remove UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this going to be working on a scrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Add the tap gesture to NewAccountScrollView in ViewDidLoad Method.

```
 let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapGestureCaptured:")
    NewAccountScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
```

and hide keyboard after receiving tap.

```
func singleTapGestureCaptured(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Should I add the func singleTapGestureCaptured(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
} this function in viewDidload as well?

Comment: I added them. But when I touched on the screen the simulator stopped and I got a signal SIGABRT!